# Save a process as workflow for documentation

Tags: microsoft-visio, documentation, workflow

I would like to document a process/workflow that we follow for a task. And I think Visio would be better.

But I want the default view of the workflow as a collapsed/summarized view and provide a description upon clicking on a shape. Is there any software that could do that?

Image below for reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no collapsed/expanded view option in Visio.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no such settings. Consider to use another drawing for sub-process to workaround it as "expanded". For example:

1. Create two pages: Page 1 for main process, and page 2 for sub-process.
2. Select one shape which you want to expand in Page 1, click **Developer** tab, in the **Shape Design** group, click **Behavior.**
3. In Behavior window, select **Double-click** tab, select **Go to page: Page 2**.
   [image]
4. Click **OK**.

Double click the shape in Page 1 to expand details in page 2.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This might come in hand, some other time.

But in this case, I just want it to be expanded when clicked, as this is not a sub-process, it's just a brief description of the step/task for anyone looking at it for the first time.

Comment: ok..Unfortunately, there is no "expanded" feature available in Visio app currently. So sad :( Maybe you can submit a feedback in Visio uservoice.